# IOS: problem with AlertView and keyboard on iPad

Tags: ios, xcode, keyboard, uialertview

I have in a view this method

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
[textField1 becomeFirstResponder];}
```

then when I open this view I have my keyboard ready to write in textField1, and it's all right.

but when I show a simply alert view

```
UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"ok!" 
                                                        message:@"It's all right"
                                                       delegate:nil 
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alertView show];
    [alertView release];
```

when I press "ok" in alert view my keyboard disappears and reappears after automatically. Why I have this effect? Can I leave this effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try implementing UITextFieldDelegate's method

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
```

Example implementation:

```
- (void)showAlertView
{
     // declared as @property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL shouldHideKeyboard
     self.shouldHideKeyboard = NO;

     // code to show alert view here
     // set the alert view's delegate to self
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    return self.shouldHideKeyboard;
}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    self.shouldHideKeyboard = YES;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand...what I should write inside this method?

Comment: That the text field should not end editing when the alert is shown, so the keyboard doesn't disappear.

Comment: I'm not able to solve this problem...can you make an example?